# backbone collection get list of single attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am wanting to get a list from my collection, the list will be used to add options to a select list. I am wanting to use this to filter the collection,

So for example I am want filter my collection by the group attributes, so first I need to get all the DISTINCT groups from my collection, i.e no repeats, I know I can do something like,

`this.collection.where({ group: "group name"});`

but is there a way to return a list of attributes for the models in a collection without having to query by a key word?

What I want in the end is something like this,

```
<select>
   <option>Filter by Group</option>
   <option value="organisation 1">Organisation 1</option>
   <option value="toms organisation">Tom's Organisation</option>
   <option value="Acme">Acme</option>
</select>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: The models in your collection have the same attribute keys or? If so it's easy, otherwise I can't see a better way than looping over the models and collecting all the keys

Comment: All the models will have an attribute key of group.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `pluck()` [collection method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-pluck) with `_.uniq()` [Underscore method](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq):

```
_.uniq(this.collection.pluck('group'))
```